# How to write in new line with laravel tinker

Tags: laravel, tinker

How can I break to a new line using laravel tinker?

So instead of:
`$users = User::all(); foreach($users as $user) {echo $user->email;}`

I want to be able to write it as follows:

```
$users = User::all();

foreach($users as $user) {
   echo $user->email;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I just tried it and opening a curly brace `{` changes the terminal from `>>>` to `...` and only executes the block when I put in a `}` so... yes it works. You really should try these things out first. That's the whole point of tinkering

Comment: @apokryfos I did try it before posting my question, and it doesn't change the terminal to `...`

Comment: Ok, never mind I understand what you mean now. I should write `{` at first and then hit Enter. I searched about this before posting my question but didn't find any info... Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Pipe your code into tinker i.e.:

`cat yourcode.php | php artisan tinker`

I think this might be the closest you'll get to what you want in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

You can break line using `"\n"`.

Example:

```
$users = User::all();

foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user->email . "\n";
}
```

**OBS:** Your `"\n"` needs to be inside a **DOUBLE QUOTES**

Comment: this does not answer the question. This is about tinker, not php

Answer (score -1):

You can write code multiple line Windows User: Ctrl + Enter

Comment: This doesnt work, it submits the line.