# Laravel Artisan Tinker : write command on multiple lines

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, tinker

How can I write a command on two lines with Laravel Artisan Tinker ?

```
User::whereEmail('john.doe@home.com')
->get()
```

> PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR on line 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write in new line with laravel tinker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542285/how-to-write-in-new-line-with-laravel-tinker)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `\` character to force the REPL into multi-line input mode:

```
>>> User::whereEmail('john.doe@home.com') \
... -> get()
```

Answer (score 10):

You can type `edit`, which launches an external editor and loads the generated code into the input buffer.

Comment: Wow this is huge! What a great tip 

Answer (score 0):

If I'm going to write several lines of code, I usually prefer a dedicated 'experiment' route over `tinker`. It becomes somewhat [`Tinkerwell`](https://tinkerwell.app/) like.

```
Route::get('/experiment', function () {
    User::whereEmail('john.doe@home.com')
        ->get();
});
```

With [`Xdebug`](https://xdebug.org/) set up, you can watch variables, trace the code line by line etc.

If you are concerned about publishing the experiment route, you may block it in the production with something like the following line before your experiment code:

```
Route::get('/experiment', function () {
    app()->isProduction() && abort(403, 'This route is only for experimenting.');

    return User::whereEmail('john.doe@home.com')
        ->get();
});
```

Note that I've also added a `return`. It is useful if you don't bother using a debugging tool (like Xdebug). You can easily see the return value where you trigger the route from.